# Как в django admin отслеживать события?

Tags: django, django-admin

Нужно при просмотре определённой записи в админ панеле django отследить событие просмотра и в этой же записи поставить автоматически флаг "Прочитано"

Не смог найти в интернете информации по этой теме, подскажите как это сделать?